# determining abelian groups of a certain size up to isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Say the size is 360. My book uses this as an example. It says there are 6 distinct groups up to isomorphism:

1. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$
2. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$
3. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$
4. $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$
5. $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$
6. $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_9 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$

The only result I have to use right now is that "$\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ iff gcd($m$, $n$) = $1$". From this result, I know (6) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{360}$ and that (1-5) are not. But how can I show that each group in (1-5) is not isomorphic to a different group in (1-5)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me do an easier example. What if the size were 60? Then we might have $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$.

These cannot be isomorphic because $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_5$ are not isomorphic (your theorem has iff, not just if), and taking the product of two non-isomorphic groups by the same group will not make them isomorphic.

The same idea works for size 360, but with a bit more legwork.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I understand that intuitively. I just wanted that statement made formal.

Comment: @blah6: Are you planning on writing it up more formally than I've given to you, or will this get you by?

Comment: What you said is fine. I just wanted somebody to confirm the reasoning, as the book doesn't seem to provide it and it isn't  made formal.